# Using Font Awesome within Xamarin Forms sometimes shows weird icons

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I used following tutorial to use font awesome icons in my xamarin forms project: https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4

I'm using xamarin forms 4 and font awesome icons 5. Actually only tested with android.

Sometimes the icon will be shown and sometimes it just shows a square with a slash or an asian character..
It's weird, because when I have a list and for every item I want to show a character, the character will be shown correctly for the first item, but not for all the others on the same page!

What's wrong with it?

Example how it looks like:

[image]

You can see that the first icons within the list are shown, but all the others not and it's just a DataTemplate within a ListView..

My code:

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XXX.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

          <!-- Icons -->
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" />
            </OnPlatform>

            ...

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

FontAwesomeIcons.cs:

```
namespace XXX.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unicode values for all FontAwesome icons.
    /// <para/>
    /// See https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet
    /// <para/>
    /// This code was automatically generated by FA2CS (https://github.com/matthewrdev/fa2cs).
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class FontAwesomeIcons
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// fa-500px unicode value.
        /// <para/>
        /// This icon supports the following styles: Brands
        /// <para/>
        /// See https://fontawesome.com/icons/500px
        /// </summary>
        public const string FiveHundredPX = "\uf26e";

        /// <summary>
        /// fa-abacus unicode value.
        /// <para/>
        /// This icon supports the following styles: Light (Pro), Regular (Pro), Solid (Pro)
        /// <para/>
        /// See https://fontawesome.com/icons/abacus
        /// </summary>
        public const string Abacus = "\uf640";

        /// <summary>
        /// fa-accessible-icon unicode value.
        /// <para/>
        /// This icon supports the following styles: Brands
        /// <para/>
        /// See https://fontawesome.com/icons/accessible-icon
        /// </summary>
        public const string AccessibleIcon = "\uf368";

        ...
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<base:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:base="clr-namespace:XXX.Pages.Base;assembly=XXX"
                xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:XXX.Utils"
                x:Class="XXX.Pages.XXXPage">

    <base:BasePage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ...>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                             Padding="10"
                                             x:Name="ItemStackLayout">

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="{x:Static utils:FontAwesomeIcons.Map}"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
                                               WidthRequest="35"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding XXX}" 
                                               LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                               FontSize="13"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    ...

                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </base:BasePage.Content>
</base:BasePage>
```

My files:

[image]

Comment: You will need to show us some of your existing code so we can take a look at how you are currently trying to implement the above solution.

Comment: I've done like it is described in the tutorial. So the code looks like the code posted within the tutorial..

Here is an example of a label within a xaml-file:

<Label Text="{x:Static utils:FontAwesomeIcons.Map}"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
            WidthRequest="35"/>

Comment: I've looked at the tutorial, but if it's not working it's something related to the way you are implementing it, hence the request to see your code. Your answer will get down-voted quickly if it doesn't supply your interpretation of the code. We can't critique the tutorial or assume you've implemented it correctly without the code.

Comment: Did you set the Bundle Action?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt: I added the code now

Comment: @AndroDevil: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: There are certain cases where FontAwesome mentions that the icon is in a certain font file but it happens to be in another, You might wanna try checking whether this works when you use another font family in place of the one mentioned by FontAwesome, Feel free to revert in case of queries

Comment: @G.hakim But when the same icon should be shown on one page 5 times, but only one time it will be shown correctly and 4 times as asian characters, that couldn't be..

Comment: So you are 100% sure that the same icon exists in the same font family but not showing in certain cases, is that the issue?

Comment: Question is not explained properly and no meaning to use onplatform twice down voting for the same.

Comment: @G.hakim: I added a picture, where you can see that the icon will be shown for the first element, but not for the others.

Comment: @KiShOrE: I added a picture now, is the question now explained properly or do you have another question?

Comment: @everydayXpert  I created a demo to verify this question, for some images it works ok, but for some images, it failed just as the case you said. Maybe you could only use the  images that can be displayed.

Comment: @JessieZhang: Can you please provied the demo, if you already created one?
Yes actually i just pick some specific icons, but that shouldn't be a good solution :-/

Comment: @everydayXpert You can check the link : https://github.com/jessiezh0320/FontApp

Answer (score -1):

Use the styles like below,

```
<!-- Icons -->
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                    x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands"
                    Android="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
```